# urllib.request error while trying to set up an SMS gateway using a Huawei E3531 3G dongle

Tags: python, sms, urllib, 3g, dongle

Here's my code:

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://192.168.8.1/api/dialup/dial"

data = "<request><Action>1</Action></request>"
data = data.encode("utf-8")

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/xml"}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, data = data, headers = headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

print(response.getcode())
print(response.read())
```

The output is:

```
200

b'< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >\r\n< error >\r\n< code >125002< /code >\r\n< message >< /message >\r\n< /error >\r\n'
```

(spaces added)

I can connect to the dongle through a web browser and connect and send messages manually.
Why am I getting this error, and what does it mean?

Comment: What happens if you open `http://192.168.8.1/api/dialup/dial` without data and the headers? What response does a browser get when you open `http://192.168.8.1/api/dialup/dial` in it?

Comment: I get a blank website with the text number 100001 in the top left corner.  There's nothing else on the page.  Does this number mean something?  Thank you!